# how to use Ajax to fetch image on click without refreshing whole page

Tags: ajax, database

How to use Ajax to fetch images from database using hyperlinks.

Hyperlinks are on the left of my webpage .xhoosing those hyperlinks a block in the page should get refreshed and show images fetched from a particular user

Comment: What do you have so far?

Answer (score 0):

Just like any other ajax request.

```
$.ajax({
    'type': "GET",
    'url': "IMAGE_URL",
    'dataType': "image/png", // Or whatever format you need.
    'success': function(data) {
        // Updated DOM however you like
        // data is your image
    },
    'error': function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        // Error occurred.
    }
    'complete':function() {
        // stuff TODO after success or error (optional)
    }
});
```